# Why are these bean plant leaves misshapen?

Tags: diagnosis, green-beans

I've planted a few rows of green bush beans and some of the sprouts have misshapen leaves (see images below). Some beans are perfectly fine whereas others are totally mangled.

The soil is sandy but I amended with a store-bought soil for vegetables. Seeds were from a reputable supplier. I'm in southern Ontario, Canada.

I've grown bush and pole beans for several years in this garden without issue. I'm not sure if it's a virus or an issue with watering. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image: Bush bean misshapen leaf]
[image: Another bush bean misshapen leaf]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bean sprouts have had mangled cotyledons in the past too, and it seems to be physical damage to the young leaves. For instance, perhaps the bean skin was too tough for the leaves to emerge without harm. My plants with this problem (and the absence of others) have always gone on to produce healthy true leaves and continue in life without a problem.

If the bean skin was the cause, it could be because the beans were watered sufficiently in the early stages of growth, but then the skin was allowed to dry out and become tough as the seed leaves emerged, scarring the leaves.

Comment: That makes sense, I watered them well in the days after planting but missed a day or two around the time they started germinating. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect contaminated soil from herbicides such as aminopyralids.

I also bought new vegetable potting mix, i.e. miracle grow organics, from a big box hardware store this summer. I decided to do a bean test in the soil after 2/3 of my herb transplants died in it. The rest of my herbs were stunted.

The bean leaves in the new potting mix soil look just like the OP’s picture, while the bean leaves in my control look normal. That soil came from a 5yr old raised bed.